# Typeid not functioning correctly

Tags: c++, typeid

I cannot get typeid function correctly.
Am I missing something

Code:

```
class A
{
     public:
     int a1;
     A()
    {
    }
};


class B: public A
{
    public:
    int b1;
    B()
    {
    }
};


int main()
{
     B tempb;
     A tempa;
     A * ptempa;
     ptempa = &tempb;

     std::cout << typeid(tempb).name() << std::endl;
     std::cout << typeid(tempa).name() << std::endl;
     std::cout << typeid(*ptempa).name() << std::endl;

     return 0;
}
```

It always prints:

Class B
Class A
Class A

I am using VS2010 for my project

Comment: It behaves the same using Clang 4.2.  I agree it looks wrong. From the documentation definition typeid gives the type of what is pointed at not the type of the pointer. Sorry that's no help. Moral support...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The object it points to must be polymorphic for this to work as you expect. If `A` had `virtual` methods than your code would have work as expected, for example adding a virtual destructor, which I [demo live here using gcc](http://rextester.com/PPI9073).

Quote form the [C++ draft standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `5.2.8` *Type identification* paragraph *2* says:

> When typeid is applied to a glvalue expression whose type is a
>   polymorphic class type (10.3), the result refers to a std::type_info
>   object representing the type of the most derived object (1.8) [...]

Which applies to the case where we have a `virtual` method, in your case you do not have a polymorphic type so paragraph *3* applies:

> When typeid is applied to an expression other than a glvalue of a
>   polymorphic class type, the result refers to a std::type_info object
>   representing the static type of the expression

So you will get the `static` type back which is `A`.

Just to be a little more complete section `10.3` *Virtual functions* says:

> Virtual functions support dynamic binding and object-oriented
>   programming. A class that declares or inherits a virtual function is
>   called a polymorphic class.

Answer (score 21):

The problem is that `A` has no virtual functions, so is not treated as a polymorphic type. As a result, `typeid` looks up the declared type of the pointer, not the actual type of the object that it points to.

Comment: Ahham. Good to know! (And you were right, the `dynamic_cast<>` doesn't even compile.

Comment: At the least, any class that is designed to be inherited from should have its dtor virtual. So I'd call OP's design incorrect.

Comment: @KitsuneYMG - `std::iterator` is designed to be derived from and does not have a virtual destructor. And that's the way it should be.

Comment: @PeteBecker I stand corrected. If your class is completely eliminated from generated code and doesn't contribute to layout because it's empty, then yeah, you don't need a virtual dtor.

Answer (score 0):

Having thought about it while mowing the lawn... A pointer cannot know what type of object it is pointing at. The type information is stored with the pointer and this is not changed by pointing at a derived class (B).  So you need a typecast to change the type of a pointer and the output IS as expected.