# Typeid issues to determine what data is processed

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism, typeid

Why does this return false and how can I fix it? I'm trying to make a program that writes data to a file and can read that file back in and display it. Also, there are 3 classes. One is a parent class (MyEmployee not displayed) and the Hourly and Salaried classes are child classes.

```
  for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
        {
            MyEmployee* empPtr = payroll[i];
            if (typeid(*empPtr) == typeid(Hourly))
            {
                Hourly* empHPtr = static_cast<Hourly*>(empPtr);
            }
            else if (typeid(*empPtr) == typeid(Salaried))
            {
                Salaried* empSPtr = static_cast<Salaried*>(empPtr);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
        {
            payroll[i]->writeData(myWrittenFile);
        }
```

Comment: Sounds like a job for a virtual function.

Comment: It returns false? Where are the return statements exactly???

Comment: The program has been set to return an error value if the data is out of order or non existent. I have written the classes precisely (and had them double checked) because they output correctly because the file is implemented correct, but it returns this error message every time the code is implemented. Another user had mentioned that this will always return false: (typeid(*empPtr) == typeid(Salaried)) I don't know why.

Comment: Is MyEmployee polymorphic? If not, you will always get the [static type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147864/typeid-not-functioning-correcly/18149769#18149769). Otherwise provide an SSCCE.

Comment: You need to show the definitions of `MyEmployee`, `Hourly`, and `Salaried`.

Answer (score 0):

If `MyEmployee` is polymorphic use `dynamic_cast < type-id > ( expression )`
This Converts the operand expression to an object of type type-id and will return 0 if the conversion fails.

```
MyEmployee* empPtr = payroll[i];
if (dynamic_cast<Hourly*>(empPtr))
{
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to guess that your class hierarchy is:

```
struct MyEmployee { virtual ~MyEmployee() {}; /* ... */ };

struct Hourly : MyEmployee { /* ... */ };
struct Salaried : MyEmployee { /* ... */ };
```

If so, then you could replace your code with:

```
MyEmployee *empPtr = payroll[i];
Hourly *empH = dynamic_cast<Hourly *>(empPtr);
Salaried *empS = dynamic_cast<Salaried *>(empPtr);
```

The `empH` and `empS` will be null if the object was not of that type; and a valid pointer if it was of that type.

Of course, it may be better to replace this whole thing with a virtual function, as chris suggested.