# Strange behavior of run-time type information

Tags: c++, rtti, typeid

I've two class `Base` and `Derived` as this:

```
class Base
{
public:
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
};
```

and main function:

```
int main()
{
    Base* ptr = new Derived;

    std::cout << typeid(*ptr).name() << endl;

    delete ptr;

    system("pause");
}
```

Program outputs shows `class Base` where I expected it will show `class Derived`. But when I've added a virtual method in the `Base` class, now outputs shows `class Derived`!

Why RTTI needs at least one virtual method?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Typeid not functioning correcly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18147864/1708801), basically if you add virtual methods you will get the result you desire.

Comment: If you were writing a compiler, how would you implement `typeid`? I'd probably do it as a hidden virtual method. But if the class doesn't have any virtual methods (and thus no vtable), this is impossible. I think the C++ spec was written to accommodate this.

Comment: You declared `ptr` as `Base*`. What else do you expect? It's not like Java who has runtime type checking. C++ is entirely static.

Comment: @texasbruce: Sure but the program gives expected result when the `Base` class has at least one virtual method and that was my point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the language specification says so. RTTI only works on polymorphic types; that is, types with virtual functions. For other types, `typeid` returns the type info for the static type of its argument.

If you're asking for a rationale for this: it has a run-time cost (typically, a pointer in each object to the per-class metadata, which supports both virtual dispatch and RTTI), and it would be a shame if you had to pay that price for all types, whether or not you want to use RTTI on them.

Answer (score 0):

[Too long for a comment.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid)

> 1) Refers to a std::type_info object representing the type type. If
>   type is a reference type, the result refers to the referenced type. 
> 2)
>   Examines the expression expression 
> a) **If expression is a glvalue
>   expression that identifies an object of a polymorphic type** (that is, a
>   class that declares or inherits at least one virtual function), **the
>   typeid expression evaluates the expression and then refers to the
>   std::type_info object that represents the dynamic type of the
>   expression**. If the result of the evaluated expression is a null
>   pointer, an exception of type std::bad_typeid or a type derived from
>   std::bad_typeid is thrown. 
> b) **If expression is not a glvalue
>   expression of polymorphic type, typeid does not evaluate the
>   expression, and the std::type_info object it identifies represents the
>   static type of the expression**. Lvalue-to-rvalue, array-to-pointer, or
>   function-to-pointer conversions are not performed.

Thus the behavior is expected, since in one case the class is polymorphic, and in the other it's not.